# Set GitHub default branch through API call

Tags: api, github, branch

I need to create a branch `dev` which is other than `master` branch. Also need to set `dev` as default branch using GITHUB API.

Please share details if anyone know which API to call or a way to do it, programmatically. I know that it can be done through the Web UI, however I am looking for a solution that does not involve manual intervention.

Answer (score 14):

I don't have enough reputation to reply to the Adam's comment above but the problem is `name` is a required field. The JSON should actually be:

```
PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo
{
"name":":repo"
"default_branch": "dev"
}
```

Comment: The name field is not required, just the default branch. I just successfully tried it with just the one field.

Answer (score 7):

Following the guide here: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#edit , `default_branch` input should make what you want

> default_branch (string): Updates the default branch for this repository.

So, you should submit a `PATCH` request like:

```
PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo

{"default_branch": "dev"}
```

Comment: I tried this (with the real constants filled out) but it says it cannot find the branch though I know it is on the remote. 
 Is there something I'm missing?`curl -i -u username --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PATCH --data '{"default_branch": "origin/develop" }'  https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo`

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to update the default branch if you have the [github cli](https://github.com/cli/cli):

```
gh api repos/{owner}/{repo} --method PATCH --field 'default_branch=dev'
```

Note the CLI will replace the `{owner}` and `{repo}` for you if you are in the locally checked out repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can use requests library:

```py
import requests
access_token = "your_access_token"
headers = {'Authorization': f'token {access_token}', 
           'Content-Type':'application/json'}
data={"name":"knowledge-engine", "default_branch": "development"}
owner = "username"
repo_name = "repo_name"
url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo_name}"
requests.patch(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
<Response [200]>
```

Docs:

- https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line
- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/
- https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#edit