# Change default branch via CLI

Tags: github

I have been looking for a way to change the default branches of a bunch of my repositories (>50). Thus I am trying to make a bash script to do it for me.

However every answer I find, e.g. [Deleting remote master branch, refused due to being the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040754/deleting-remote-master-branch-refused-due-to-being-the-current-branch?noredirect=1&lq=1), tells me to "go to the setting page on GitHub".

Can you do it *without* the UI?

Comment: You can do it through the _API_ - per e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52776313/3001761 - which you could certainly do from a bash script. Or do you mean the specific GitHub CLI, in which case did you [read the fine manual](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So deep down the rabbit call of the API doc I found that you can do such thing:

```
gh api repos/{owner}/{repo} --method PATCH --field 'default_branch=main' --silent
```

Comment: If you're using the GitHub CLI you don't _need_ to do it via the API.

Comment: Well can you tell how then ? I've look at the docs but nothing works there.

Comment: I linked to it in the comment on the question. If you tried the docs and it doesn't work, that should be _in the question_ as part of showing your research.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it directly with the [`gh repo edit`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit) command of the GitHub CLI like this:

```bash
gh repo edit {owner}/{repo} --default-branch main
```

or if you have set a [*default remote repository*](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_set-default), you can execute the command in the local repository without specifying the owner & repository:

```bash
gh repo edit --default-branch main
```

Please note that the new default branch must already exist, otherwise there will be a validation error.

Answer (score 0):

And here's a script to rename all your master branches to main.

It will:

- install the dorian-each gem for the `each` command line that executes ruby on each line
- for each repo

  - clone the repo
  - go to the repo's directory
  - create the main branch
  - push the main branch
  - change the default branch to main
  - delete the master branch locally and remotely

```
gem install dorian-each
gh repo list --limit 1000 | each "puts l.split.first" | each "l = l.strip; puts l;`gh repo clone #{l}`; Dir.chdir(l.split('/').last) { `git checkout -b main`; `git push`; `gh repo edit #{l} --default-branch main`; `git branch -d master`; `git push origin :master` }"
```

edit: I'm the author of the dorian-each gem

Comment: Please be aware that you **must** disclose affiliation where needed. Please read [how to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), then [edit] your answer to include proper disclosure. Failure to do so will result in your post being [deleted](//%SITEURL%/help/deleted-answers), along with other consequences.

Comment: @Fastnlight I disclosed that I'm the author of the dorian-each gem, it's just what I use to do some programs